# Changing the class name generated by ClistView Yii

Tags: yii, clistview

Just a simple question, is it possible to change the classname generated by `ClistView` ?

by default,  it generates

```
<div class="post">
```

for all the list.

I'd like to have

```
<div class=post1>

<div class=post2>
```

...

Comment: I don't remember having class="post" to be used by ClistView, see an example here: http://www.eha.ee/labs/yiiplay/index.php/en/person/index It doesn't have this class.

Answer (score 4):

You can customize CListView styles with bellow parameters:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
'dataProvider'=>$YOUR_DATA_PROVIDET,
'itemView'=>'...',
'sortableAttributes'=>array(),
'cssFile'=>' YOU CAN ASSIGN A CSS FILE TO YOUR CLISTVIEW',
'itemsCssClass'=>'SOME CLASS',
'pagerCssClass'=>'SOME CLASS',
'sorterCssClass'=>'SOME CLASS',
'summaryCssClass'=>'SOME CLASS',
));
```

for more information you can check CListView's Official document in the following link:

[CListView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CListView)

**UPDATE:**

If you want to change other names, you must edit the source of yii's CGridView. But changing the style of it could be more easier.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a different, incrementing class on *each looped list item*, change your itemView partial like this:

using the ID of each model:

```
<div class="post<?php print $data->id; ?>"> 
<?php

print_r($data->attributes); // Or whatever

?>
</div>
```

using the 'index' of the current iteration:

```
<div class="post<?php print $index; ?>"> 
<?php

print_r($data->attributes); // Or whatever

?>
</div>
```

More info available [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CListView#itemView-detail)